# How to setup Keycloak in High Availability

Tags: keycloak, high-availability

I’m wondering if it’s possible to setup Keycloak In High-Availability. If yes could you give some advices ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it`s possible

Have you considered to check Keycloak documentation regarding this topic?

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_clustering

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_operating-mode (e.g. Standalone Clustered Mode)

If you need additional help, please add more information to your question. But it would be nice if you read the documentation first :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I read it and i tried a domain clustered mode install but i'm wondering how it work for example if one worker or master fail in term of HA